# Conceptual model with a constraint

Tags: uml, conceptual-model

I'm trying to make a conceptual model of this use case:

> The `Actor` can modify the `budget` but after the modification the sum of
>   all the budget elements `percentages` must be `100%` or `0%` if there are
>   no elements in the budget.

How can I include this constraint in my model?
[image]
The model can also be found [here](http://yuml.me/edit/0e14e3d1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just put a constraint on the `contains` property. In MagicDraw one can show the label for a constraint or the actual constraint in OCL.

Here is an example with the label only, which is probably more appropriate for the audience of a conceptual model:

[image]

Here is an example with OCL:

[image]

A little less readable, eh?

Answer (score 2):

Simply attach the constraint like this to `Budget`

[image]

You can simply use a Note and put the constraint in curly brackets if your tool does not provide a native constraint element.